# NSLocale is mostly empty - where are the attributes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nslocale

I really just want to know whether the user has set the iPhone to 12 hour mode for time display.

The `NSLocale` class seemed to be describing (in vague unspecific terms without any examples or apparently useful methods) what I was after.

So I have created some `NSLocale` objects like so:

```
NSLocale *systemLocaleApparently = [NSLocale systemLocale];
NSLocale *currentLocaleWithLotsOfGoodies = [NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale];
```

When I inspect these objects using the debugger or `NSLog()`, the best I can get is something along these lines:

```
<CFLocale 0x1278e0 [0x382084f8]>{type = system, identifier = ''}
```

The current locale has an ID string in it, but nothing else.

From the documentation, I can lookup values from the locale, and one of these is an `NSCalendar` object. So I get that back and have a look at it, and it tells me it is "gregorian".

All of which is apparently of use to somebody... but what I would really like is a nice big dictionary of attributes showing all of the actual system properties, mainly so that my `NSDateFormatters` don't keep blowing up when a user chooses 12 hour format even though I have forced the formatters to use `en_US_POSIX` locale and a fixed `setDate` format.

(I'm sure `NSCalendarDate` never used to have these problems...)

Hopefully I am missing something blatantly (and probably embarrassingly) obvious, but perhaps someone kind would share it with me. Please :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to tell if the user has set their time format to a 12- or 24-hour format:

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
// Look for H (24-hour format) vs. h (12-hour format) in the date format.
NSString* dateFormat = [formatter dateFormat];
BOOL using24HourClock = [dateFormat rangeOfString:@"h"].location == NSNotFound;
```

Comment: Thanks Tyler that was very useful. After some refactoring NSDateFormatter appears to be doing the right thing now too (meaning I no longer need to explicitly check :)). Many thanks for the response!